# Trying to get property of non-object when i use num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I had code which will register the users information to database, and before save them into database has to check if the email address exists or not. They all work fine but always give me an error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in X:\xampp\htdocs\csg2431\week4\registerUser.php on line 72

Here is the code form line 72

```
$email_query = "SELECT EmailAddress FROM userdetails WHERE EmailAddress = '".$emailAddress."'";
$email_results = $db->query($email_query);

if (isset($emial_results))
{
    $error_message ='Your database is empty.';
}

if ($email_results->num_rows > 0)  // this is line 72
{
    $error_message = 'Your email address already exists, choose anther.';
}

if ($error_message != '')
{
    echo 'Error: '.$error_message. '<a href="javascript: history.back();">Go Back</a>.';
    echo '</body></html>';
    exit;
}
```

It also happend to my other page to search the user information from the database,

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in X:\xampp\htdocs\csg2431\week4\searchUsers.php on line 43

here is some code:

```
$results = $db->query($query);

echo '<p>'.$results->num_rows.' users found.</p>'; // this is line 43

while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo '<p><strong>Name: </strong>'. $row['Surname'].','.$row['FirstName'].'<br />';

    echo '<strong>Gender: </strong>'. $row['Gender'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Date of Birth: </strong>'. $row['DOB'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Home Phone: </strong>'. $row['HomePhone'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Position: </strong>'. $row['Position_ID'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Room Number: </strong>'. $row['RoomNo'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Work Phone: </strong>'. $row['WorkPhone'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Fax: </strong>'. $row['Fax'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Mobile: </strong>'. $row['mobilePhone'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Email: </strong>'. $row['EmailAddress'].',<br />';

    echo '<strong>Department: </strong>'. $row['Dept_ID'].',<br /></p>';
}
```

It looks like every time when I use `num_rows` the error happens

Comment: make sure that `$emailAddress` is not null/empty. and put `die($db->error)`

Comment: Not sure if c/p error, but `$emial_results` is misspelled.

Comment: $email_results is not a object means you don't have result from the query and `isset($emaill_results)` is always true here

Comment: Change `if (isset($emial_results))` to `if (isset($email_results))`

Comment: Thanks guys i think i found my probelem, in my database the table called "userdetetails" which is misspelled but in may php code i spelled it correct like "userdetails"!